# Is there a simple way to create a custom VS action for personalised comments?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, macros, shortcut, visual-studio-macros

Feel free to massively re-word this question.

Basically, I'm currently stripping out a huge portion of a very large framework - this involves A LOT of commenting. So I can find all of this later I am batch commenting and then copy-pasting a marker before each block that is something like this:

```
//MYINITIALS_REMOVE
/*if (this code is rubbish)
{
    comment it out;
}*/
```

I'd like to create a function so that with one button press or key combination I batch comment out selected code and automatically place my tag at the beginning. So instead of the opening comment being '//' or '/*' it is 'MYINITIALS_REMOVE//' or 'MYINITIALS_REMOVE/*'

Is this possible?

**EDIT** Actually thinking about it, I wouldn't even mind if every single line began with 'MYINITIALS_REMOVE//'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
Public Sub CStyleComment()
    Dim selection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
    selection.TopPoint.CreateEditPoint.Insert("//MYINITIALS_REMOV" & vbCrLf & "/*")
    selection.BottomPoint.CreateEditPoint.Insert("*/")
End Sub
```

Maybe this version is more suitable (automatic translation):

```
Public Sub CStyleComment()
    Dim selection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
    selection.TopPoint.CreateEditPoint.Insert("//MYINITIALS_REMOV" & vbCrLf & "/*")
    selection.BottomPoint.CreateEditPoint.Insert("*/")
End Sub
```